# $PV=$ constant and ${PV}^{\gamma}=$ constant. Are these constants equal?

Tags: thermodynamics, units, ideal-gas, dimensional-analysis

In Boyle's relation:

> $$PV=\textrm{constant}$$

and in an adiabatic process of an ideal gas:

> $$PV^{\gamma}=\textrm{constant}$$

In my thought the answer is clearly not, but are they at least close? To the same gas, are they experimentally compatible? Where I can find such an information?

My wondering about this point is because that in order to compare the rate of drecreasing pressure as one increases the temperature between an isothermal and an adiabatic line (is claimed to be), in absolute values, greater for the adiabatic than for the isothermal. Is there another way to see this?

Comment: They can't be equal simply because they don't have the same units... Plus, these two constants don't only depend on the gas, but also on the initial conditions of the experience: $PV = nRT$, so it depends on the temperature and the quantity of substance; if you make a non-adiabatic transformation between two adiabatic one, the constante $PV^\gamma$ will change.

Comment: This clarify a lot! Thank you. 
I should show this to explain my main question, that maybe was not so clear.
I mean how may we show that in the plane of Pressure x Volume, that the derivative of the P with respect to V assuming these relation to describe the gas (PV and PV^γ), which one is greater??

Comment: For an ideal gas, $PV=nRT$, so $P=\frac{nRT}{V}$ , and when the transformation is adiabatic, $P=P_0 (\frac{V_0}{V})^\gamma$, so once again, the derivative of P with respecct to V totally depends on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$PV$ and $PV^\gamma$ are not close because the concept of "closeness" does not apply to them. They have different units, which means that depending on how you choose your unit system, they can have the same numerical value, or $PV$ can be a million times bigger, or $PV^\gamma$ can be twenty trillion times bigger, or whatever you want.

The lesson is that no two quantities with different units can be sensibly compared..

Answer (score 3):

These constants are, in general, not equal. The constant $\gamma$ is usually larger than 1. Thus mathematically $PV≠PV^{\gamma}$ showing that the constants must be different.

Answer (score 0):

The $\gamma$ index is related to the number of degrees of freedom for an ideal gas namely $$\gamma=1+\frac{2}{n_d}$$ where $n_d$ is the number of degrees of freedom for an ideal gas. So basically $$PV\ne PV^{\gamma}$$ in general.

To address your other question about how *close* they are to each other; well this depends on $n_d$.